# UPDATE SET doesn't work with NOT IN (SELECT)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with this SQL UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE gon_nu.migration_threads 
    SET AuthorID = 461376 
WHERE AuthorID NOT IN (SELECT id AS AuthorID 
                       FROM prod_playing.users_userprofile 
                       WHERE username != 'OldPlayingUser');
```

It responds matches but 0 rows affected. How can I solve this so it updates the AuthorID to 461376 when the AuthorID doesn't exists in prod_playing.users_userprofile?

Comment: Can `id` be `NULL` in `users_userprofile`?

Comment: No, id or username can not be null.

Comment: can u list out what are the columns of the table migration_threads? and also what is the output of sub-query (SELECT id AS AuthorID FROM...)

Comment: Your query looks ok for what you want to do.  You would need to show sample data to give us an idea of why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility why your query would not work is if `users_userprofile.id` is ever `NULL` when `username = 'OldPlayingUser'`.  This suggests that this query might do what you want:

```
UPDATE gon_nu.migration_threads 
    SET AuthorID = 461376 
    WHERE AuthorID NOT IN (SELECT id AS AuthorID 
                           FROM prod_playing.users_userprofile 
                           WHERE username <> 'OldPlayingUser' and id is not null
                          );
```

However, your question suggests that you might have too many negatives in the `where` clause.  It is unusual to have `not in` used with subquery where the `where` condition is not equals.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
UPDATE gon_nu.migration_threads 
    SET AuthorID = 461376 
    WHERE AuthorID NOT IN (SELECT id AS AuthorID 
                           FROM prod_playing.users_userprofile 
                           WHERE username = 'OldPlayingUser' and id is not null
                          );
```

Comment: It was something fishy with != 'OldPlayingUser'. I removed that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer NOT EXISTS as it makes it clearer:

```
UPDATE MT
SET
AuthorID = 461376 
FROM gon_nu.migration_threads AS MT
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT ID 
            FROM prod_playing.users_userprofile AS UP
            WHERE 
                UP.id = MT.AuthorID
            AND     (UP.username != 'OldPlayingUser'
            OR  UP.username IS NULL)
           )
```

Also you can switch the update to a select easily to see what records your about to update!